# What are the reasons why PHP would echo errors, even with error_reporting(0)?

Tags: php, error-reporting, ini-set

What are some reasons why PHP would force errors to show, no matter what you tell it to disable?

I have tried

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

with no luck.

Comment: I don't know this answer, but if possible it may help if you provide an example of an error that was displayed with reporting turned off.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' in /usr/home/johnq/public_html/dev.php on line 11

the only PHP in dev.php is this:

<?php
error_reporting(0);
echo "test"
$test = "123";
?>

Comment: Without that error message, it might have taken you a lot longer to realize that your script wasn't running simply because of a missing semicolon.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note the caveat in the manual at http://uk.php.net/error_reporting:

> > Most of E_STRICT errors are evaluated at the compile time thus such errors are not reported in the file where error_reporting is enhanced to include E_STRICT errors (and vice versa).

If your underlying system is configured to report E_STRICT errors, these may be output before your code is even considered. Don't forget, error_reporting/ini_set are runtime evaluations, and anything performed in a "before-run" phase will not see their effects.

---

Based on your comment that your error is...

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' in /usr/home/REDACTED/public_html/dev.php on line 11

Then the same general concept applies. Your code is never run, as it is syntactically invalid (you forgot a ';'). Therefore, your change of error reporting is never encountered.

Fixing this requires a change of the system level error reporting. For example, on Apache you may be able to place...

php_value error_reporting 0

in a .htaccess file to suppress them all, but this is system configuration dependent.

Pragmatically, don't write files with syntax errors :)

Answer (score 3):

To prevent errors from displaying you can

- Write in a .htaccess: *php_flag display_errors 0*
- Split your code in separate modules where the
  main (parent) PHP file only sets the
  error_logging and then include() the
  other files.

Answer (score 1):

Use [phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) to find the loaded php.ini and edit it to hide errors. It overrides what you put in your script.

Answer (score 1):

Is `set_error_handler()` used anywhere in your script? This overrides `error_reporting(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use *log_errors* for them to be logged instead of displayed.

Comment: <?php
ini_set('error_log','/error_log');
ini_set('log_errors',TRUE);
echo "test"
$test = "123";
?>

Still causes the same error, unfortunately. I'm looking for a way to do this without modifying php.ini. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If the setting is specified in Apache using *php_admin_value*, it can't be changed in .htaccess or at runtime.

See: *[How to change configuration settings](http://docs.php.net/configuration.changes)*

Answer (score 0):

> Pragmatically, don't write files with syntax errors :)

To ensure there's no syntax errors in your file, run the following:

```
php -l YOUR_FILE_HERE.php
```

This will output something like this:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in Connection.class.php on line 31
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below code in your **index.php** file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', False);
```