# Updating MySQL to mysqli prepared

Tags: php, mysqli

I have decide to update my old MySQL code to mysqli but when creating a SELECT query it is just showing a white page here is my code

```
<?php
session_start();
include('./includes/connections.php');
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$chk_name = $db->prepare("SELECT `playerid`
             FROM `members` 
             WHERE `playername` = '?' ||
                   `player_login_name` = '?'";
$chk_name->bind_param($_POST['name'],$_POST['name'])
$chk_name->execute();
$chk_name->fetch();
$exsist = $chk_name->num_rows;
if($exsist) 
{ 
  echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sorry, This username is already in use.<br/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;<a href='home.php";
        if($_GET['PID']) { echo '?PID=' . $_GET['PID']; } echo "'>Okay</a>";
}
else{
    echo "username available";
}
```

here is my connection script `

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "******", "*****", "******");
if($db->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Connection failed [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
```

Comment: You missed a `;` at this line : `$exsist = $chk_name->num_rows`.

Comment: yes i realised that i just missed it off while copying it over it is in my file and still nothing

Comment: If the page is blank, you should have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78296/reasons-why-php-would-echo-errors-even-with-error-reporting0) to configure errors displaying.

Comment: Still a `;` missing here : `$chk_name->bind_param($_POST['name'],$_POST['name'])`. ;)

Comment: fyi: you do not need quotations on those placeholders

Comment: i have error reporting switched on but it still shows blank and i have added the ; into that line to no avail

Comment: Change `error_reporting(-1)` into `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. What do you see? There must be some kind of error if it only shows a blank page.